# From the perspective of etymology, why was the word "magma" chosen to describe a set with a single binary operation defined on it?

Tags: mathematics, terminology, abstract-algebra

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)), the choice of vocabulary was made partially to avoid overloading the term "groupoid".

However, that still does not explain etymologically speaking, "magma" was chosen instead of any other word that isn't "groupoid".

Can you explain?

Comment: Look here: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/63255/9368

Comment: One of Bourbaki's best coinings!

Comment: @MariusKempe Actually, Serre used it first (according to Wikipedia).

Comment: @user89: evidently neither you nor Wikipedia are aware that Bourbaki's Algebra was first published in the 40s...

Comment: @MariusKempe Evidently.

Comment: The [first English translation](http://www.cmat.edu.uy/~marclan/TM/Algebra%20i%20-%20Bourbaki.pdf) of Nicolas Bourbaki, [Algèbre: Chapitres 1 à 3](https://books.google.it/books?id=4RIDPH1ULXcC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) (1970) refers to 1943 as first pubblication date. As you can see the def of *magma* is the first one (page I-1), under the heading : **1. Lois de composition**. The corresponding [draft](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/archives-bourbaki/PDF/033bis_iecnr_041.pdf) (rédaction n°033 bis : what date ?) does not have the term *magma*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: You are quite right, I only assumed that Bourbaki used 'magma' in the first (1942) edition: I have never seen this book and my library does not have it, and the evidence seems to suggest that it did not in fact use 'magma' (e.g. 'magma' does not appear in *Math Reviews* until the time of the 2nd edition).

Comment: Indeed - nicely found. I stick by my first comment, since, of course, Serre was a member of Bourbaki.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Why don't you post all this as an answer?

Comment: Discussion on [MathOverflow Meta](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2297/appropriate-to-ask-question-regarding-choice-of-magma-to-describe-simple-algeb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the mathematical usage of *magma*, it seems that the origin is the "Bourbaki circle", but it is not so easy to trace exactly the date ...

The [first English translation](http://www.cmat.edu.uy/~marclan/TM/Algebra%20i%20-%20Bourbaki.pdf) of Nicolas Bourbaki, [Algèbre: Chapitres 1 à 3](https://books.google.it/books?id=4RIDPH1ULXcC) (1970) dates the first pubblication to 1943.

As you can see, the definition of *magma* is the first one (page I-1), under the heading : **1. Lois de composition**.

The corresponding [draft](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/archives-bourbaki/PDF/033bis_iecnr_041.pdf) (rédaction n°033 bis : what date ?) does not have the term *magma*.

I'm not able to find a copy od the original French edition; thus, I'm not able to check if the term was already there. It seems not ...

According to Hubert Kiechle, [Theory of K-Loops](https://books.google.it/books?id=J3id_WLGgKMC&pg=PA23), page 23 : the term magma was introduced in the 1970-edition of Bourbaki's *Algebra*.

We have also a [review](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&tbo=p&hl=it&q=magma&safe=active#hl=it&tbm=bks&q=magma+Bourbaki++Alg%C3%A8bre+I+(Paris%2C+1942)++) of the 1970 edition that seemingly alludes to *magma* as a "new entry".

For sure, the term is used by Serre in 1964 : Jean-Pierre Serre, [Lie Algebras and Lie Groups: 1964 Lectures given at Harvard University](https://books.google.it/books?id=ChJqCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA18), page 18 : **1. Free magmas**.